# Drools updateToVersion call while an instance still leveraging the rule engine?

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I am working on a system that needs a rule engine like architecture. I am storing the rules remotely and fetching them into my application every 20 minutes asynchronously.

When the rules are fetched, I am building a new KieBuilder instance(built by creating a new KieFileSystem) and using **updateToVersion()** method.

```
kieContainer.updateToVersion(kieBuilder.getKieModule().getReleaseId());
```

This updates the Knowledge Base dynamically sparing me the task of re-deploying my application.

However I wanted to know what happens to those instances that were passed to rule engine and were acted upon at the instant the updateToVersion() method is called? Do the old rules get applied to them or is the working memory cleared? This is a very likely scenario in my application and wanted to know exactly what would happen in this case.

Also, I was thinking in order to avoid any repercussions, is there a way to stop accepting/put on hold the instances into the kieSession while it gets updated?

Comment: `is there a way to stop accepting/put on hold the instances into the kieSession` ~ you could build a queuing/blocking mechanism, but that would slow down those trapped queries/increase memory usage. I've always solved this by having two instances of the app so I can upgrade them one at a time while routing traffic exclusively to the other.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas do you have any idea about what goes on with the trapped queries while the app is getting updated?